# Show dropdown every click in code igniter php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, cascadingdropdown

I have a web application in which the user can add household names dynamically and delete those name if they want to.

In my view:

```
<tr>
    <td>Add Household</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="field_wrapper">
                <div>
                    <select name="field_name[]" value="" id="drop2"  style="color:black;">
                        <?php
                              foreach ($head as $row) {
                                echo "<option style='color:black;' value='".$row['hh_id']."'>".$row['hh_fname']."  ".$row['hh_lname']."</option>";?>
       </select>
                              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="<?php echo base_url('dist/img/add-icon.png'); ?>" /></a>
                     </div>
              </div>
          </td>
   </tr>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper


var fieldHTML = '<div><select name="field_name[]"><option></option></select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="<?php echo base_url("dist/img/remove-icon.png"); ?>" /></a></div>'; //New input field html 
var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
    }
});
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
});
});
</script>
```

I want that whenever the user clicks the `add` button, the same dropdown should be shown like the first dropdown displayed. How should I achieve that in the script part? How to populate the `fieldHtml` to dropdown then?

The `add` and `remove` functions worked well. It's just that whenever there will be an addition, it should show the dropdown.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that may help you. Instead of wanting to re-open the drop-down you can go for a multiple row select:

```
<select name="field_name[]" value="" id="drop2"  style="color:black;" size="10">
```

With the `size` attribute on your `select` tag you will not have the popover drop-down but you will have a drop-down like element always visible.